# How to put expressWinston into a specific class/service?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

So I have the following code:

```
const loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston({
    projectId: CLOUD_PROJECT_ID,
    keyFilename: CLOUD_KEY_FILE,
  });
  // winston configuration for dev
  const alignColorsAndTime = winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
    winston.format.label({ label: '[LOG]' }),
    winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' }),
    winston.format.printf(
      (info) => ` ${info.label}  ${info.timestamp}  ${info.level} : ${info.message}`,
    ),
  );

  app.use(expressWinston.logger({
    level: 'info',
    transports: [
      DEV
        ? new winston.transports.Console({ format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.colorize(), alignColorsAndTime) })
        : loggingWinston,
    ],
    meta: true,
    expressFormat: true, // Use the default Express/morgan request formatting.
    colorize: true, // Color the text and status code, using the Express/morgan color palette.
  }));
```

and that works fine...

Now I would like to eliminate this logic from my index.ts and to put it into new class called WinstonService.

I am struggling because whatever I return from that class and use it like this:

```
let winstonService = new WinstonService(DEV);
app.use(winstonService.getExpressConfiguration());
```

I get:

```
"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid transport, must be an object with a log method."
```

My current class looks like this:

```
export class WinstonService {

    private dev: boolean;
    private loggingWinston: LoggingWinston;
    private alignColorsAndTime;

    constructor(dev: boolean){

        if (!dev){
            this.loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston({
              projectId: CLOUD_PROJECT_ID,
              keyFilename: CLOUD_KEY_FILE,
            });
        }

        // winston configuration for dev
        this.alignColorsAndTime = winston.format.combine(
          winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
          winston.format.label({ label: '[LOG]' }),
          winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' }),
          winston.format.printf(
            (info) => ` ${info.label}  ${info.timestamp}  ${info.level} : ${info.message}`,
          ),
        );
    }

    public getExpressConfiguration(){
        return expressWinston.logger({
            level: 'info',
            transports: [
              this.dev
                ? new winston.transports.Console({ format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.colorize(), this.alignColorsAndTime) })
                : this.loggingWinston,
            ],
            meta: true,
            expressFormat: true, // Use the default Express/morgan request formatting.
            colorize: this.dev, // Color the text and status code, using the Express/morgan color palette.
        });
    }
}

export default new WinstonService(this.dev);
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the existing code work for both DEV === true and false? the only thing that struck me as out of place was the `export default new WinstonService(this.dev)`, which will be falsey in the module scope

Comment: also `this.dev` is not being set in the constructor.  unless ts does some magic?